# PrimeFaces wizard - how can I use onstart/oncomplete for tab change ajax loading

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.
I don't want to use `p:ajaxStatus` because I only want to show loading for a few components. 
So I have a `p:blockUI` component that I usually show during ajax events by doing this:

```
onstart="loading.show();" oncomplete="loading.hide();"
```

But for `p:wizard` component I don't know how can I do that when the user change tabs (clicking next/back buttons or clicking in the tab title). I tried the following inside the wizard:

```
<p:wizard id="wizard" flowListener="#{myBean.onFlowProcess}" style="display: inline-block;" backLabel="Prev" nextLabel="Next" showNavBar="true" widgetVar="wizardWV"> 
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" onstart="loading.show();" oncomplete="loading.hide();" />
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="My tab 1">
        <p:panel>
            <h:outputLabel value="test" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2" title="My tab 2">
        <p:panel>
            <h:outputLabel value="test2" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

Then I got the error:

```
<p:ajax> Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? it's likely the p:ajax isn't inside the correct container, ie - in the wizard not the tabView.

Comment: @VeenarM please check my updated code. What do you mean by in tabView? Should I use tabView? Thanks!

Comment: On the p:wizard they have these 2 features - onback, onnext try them on the p:wizard line - I don't believe wizard has the ajax event tabChange (that's inside a tabView) but wizard is a back and forth flow, you wouldn't need to use a .hide() i believe as the whole render box get's recompleted - but I haven't tested it in a while. P.S I'm a little confused, afaik the tabs in a wizard aren't selectable, only the back/next buttons are?

Comment: @VeenarM I tried to just call `.show()` but the loading is not hidden after the other tab is loaded. The wizard'd tabs are clickable. Thanks

Comment: Just had the same problem. Use `onnext` and `onback` attributes to show your wait-dialog (as mentioned by VeenarM). And use [`PrimeFaces.executeScript()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-) in your `flowListener` method to hide the dialog. This is definitively a hack, but seems currently the only solution to get a custom AJAX-indicator for the wizard component.

Answer (score 0):

That's is because the wizard isn't a client behavior container.

The standard flow of a wizard is the tabs are just for display purposes in the heading. You should be using the Next/Back triggers for the wizard flow.

Refer to : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml
Has the basic features/flow, but some more links
http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/wizard.html

If you're trying to make your tabs clickable then that's a different story, you'll need to setup your flow listener, have them all select the same method/action as the next - but pass a param to the backing bean and manually determine the flow. You could setup a remote call in PF with an onclick attached to access your intent of the waiting on load.

I would look at use case scenarios, maybe Wizard is the wrong component you're looking for?

Looking at the code provided, you're tabs currently are not clickable, and I cannot see your back/next action buttons.

Comment: Thanks for helping! At least on PF 4, the tabs are clickable and next/back buttons are added by default. But anyway, it looks like what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible.. maybe I will have to change to `p:tabView` because "loading" for a heavy tab is very important.

Comment: would need to load it up and test the behavior. you could put javascript scripts in the page, that 'onload' it closes the spinner/blocker. so the ajax re-rendering causes it to run?